# Sql Index not working issue for 8 million data

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I had a SQL script running in SQL server, the table had about 8m lines runs about 7 secs
Anyone had any ideas how can I optimize the SQL script or my index to running fast.

```
DECLARE @number varchar(30)
set @number = '123456789'
select * from customer_info where record_status ='1' and
                                 (CUST_HANDPHONE  in (@number ,concat('00',@number ))
                                or CUST_PREFERRED_NO1 in ( @number , concat('00',@number )) 
                                or CUST_PREFERRED_NO2 in ( @number , concat('00',@number ) )
                                or CUST_PREFERRED_NO3 in (  @number , concat('00',@number ))) ;
```

I already had Non-Cluster-index for
record_status,CUST_HANDPHONE,CUST_PREFERRED_NO1,CUST_PREFERRED_NO2,CUST_PREFERRED_NO3
and Clustered index for id

but it does not working, hope I can get help.

Comment: First, remove * and replace it with fields list. may be you are trying to transfer gigabyte BLOB's to client. Second, you can try to replace OR-calculations with UNION ALL-approach

Comment: How many other columns are there? How many rows _match_? How much harder is it for you to pick out all your socks if I say "get all the socks that are blue or grey or green or fuzzy or calf-length"? In that case it's much easier to just dump the drawer on the floor (scanning the table) than pick them out one by one (seeking from an index). That's what SQL Server is doing, and in fact it is very hard to get an efficient query that properly uses an index when there is even one OR condition, never mind multiple. Having `*` also doesn't help.

Comment: Normalize your table. Create a separate table for phone numbers (one to many) and normalize the phone numbers (pad them with leading zeros) prior to storing.

Answer (score 2):

You might find that the following query makes use of multiple indexes:

- `customer_info(record_status, CUST_HANDPHONE)`
- `customer_info(record_status, CUST_PREFERRED_NO1)`
- `customer_info(record_status, CUST_PREFERRED_NO2)`
- `customer_info(record_status, CUST_PREFERRED_NO3)`

Although this query looks more complicated, splitting out the separate subqueries makes it easier to optimize:

```
select *
from customer_info
where record_status = '1' and
      CUST_HANDPHONE in (@number, concat('00',@number ))
union all
select *
from customer_info
where record_status = '1' and
      CUST_PREFERRED_NO1 in (@number, concat('00', @number )) and
      CUST_HANDPHONE not in (@number, concat('00', @number ))
union all
select *
from customer_info
where record_status = '1' and
      CUST_PREFERRED_NO2 in (@number, concat('00', @number )) and
      CUST_HANDPHONE not in (@number, concat('00', @number )) and
      CUST_PREFERRED_NO1 not in (@number, concat('00', @number ))
union all
select *
from customer_info
where record_status = '1' and
      CUST_PREFERRED_NO3 in (@number, concat('00', @number )) and
      CUST_HANDPHONE not in (@number, concat('00', @number )) and
      CUST_PREFERRED_NO1 not in (@number, concat('00', @number ))
      CUST_PREFERRED_NO2 not in (@number, concat('00', @number ));
```

The additional `not in` clauses are so you can use `union all` rather than `union` -- that is, to avoid duplicates in the results set.

Note:  If you stored the data in a normalized structure, with a table that has one row per customer and phone number, then the query would be simpler to optimize and to write.